# Sorting based on each row returned in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want data to be sorted in one oracle table based on multiple columns.

```
select userid,active,vdate from  PROD   order by vdate desc;
```

The query gives this result:

```
Userid  Active  vdate        
bb           1  16-08-2019 05:20
pe290        1  15-08-2019 05:20
aa           2  13-08-2019 06:34
aa           1  08-08-2019 06:37
pe290        3  04-08-2019 06:24
pe290        2  04-08-2019 06:24
```

But I require,  after sorting based on `vdate` column, all userids of that corresponding `vdate` to be together(in the order of Active column). My required output as below:

```
Userid  Active  vdate  
bb           1  16-08-2019 05:20
pe290        1  15-08-2019 05:20
pe290        2  04-08-2019 06:24
pe290        3  04-08-2019 06:24
aa           1  08-08-2019 06:37
aa           2  13-08-2019 06:34
```

Comment: Looks like `order by userid desc, vdate desc, active` to me ...

Comment: Your required output seems to be sorted by `userid desc` then by `vdate desc` and `active asc`. This seems to contradict your verbal explanation of the rules, which suggest you want `vdate desc, active` with no requirement to sort `userid` in any particular order. So which is correct? As you can see, a lot of people have expended energy in providing and correcting answers, because your question is not clear in explaining your requirements.

Comment: Hi,  after sorting based on vdate. I need there userid's together----here in that case pe290 is userid, so all pe290 should be together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find maximum date for each user at first, then use this value as primary sorting key. Here it is done with analytical `max()`:

```
select userid, active, vdate 
  from (
    select userid, active, vdate, max(vdate) over (partition by userid) mxd from prod) 
  order by mxd desc, userid, active;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7258baa5d234299d197080446943e812)</sup>**

Comment: @VineethChowdary . . . A subquery is not needed for this.

Comment: Yes you are correct @GordonLinoff,This is doing magic itself-----select userid, active, vdate,  max(vdate) over (partition by userid) mxd from prod
  order by mxd desc, active;

Comment: Analytic functions are evaluated at the end, so we cannot use them in `where` or `group by` clause, we need subquery, that's why I used it. `Order by` is an exception, `max() over()` is allowed here and query may be simplified. I always forget about this. Thanks @GordonLinoff.

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid,active,vdate from sampleee order by 
case when userid <>'aa' then SUBSTR(vdate,instr(vdate,' '))  else vdate  end
```

output

[image]

Comment: did you try the query ?

Comment: Yes , it's still not getting expected results

Comment: your query explanation seems different to your expected output as a workaround see my query and output i have sorted the data first by timestamp  all userids followed this order expect aa which followed the active ids order

Comment: Thanks for response, As i provided only random data in real scenario, i need to handle with thousands of records. I can't use your query.Found the solution with @pondy. once again appreciated your response and interest

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second sorting level to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select userid, active, vdate
from PROD
order by vdate desc, active;
```

This matches your actual stated requirement:

> But I require, after sorting based on vdate column all userids of that corresponding vdate to be sorted based on active column.

Based on your recent edit it seems that you want *three* levels of sorting:

```
select userid, active, vdate
from PROD
order by userid, vdate desc, active;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select userid,active,vdate from  PROD   
order by userid desc,vdate desc, active;
```

Cheers!!